# Warning C26495 on structures?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I've been using C#/.NET for the past decade or two, but am updating an old C++/MFC application for a client. I know a lot has changed since I last worked with C++, but this one kind of threw me.

I have the following structure:

```
typedef struct _FILTERINFO {
    int nCustomerID;
    CString sCustomerName;
} FILTERINFO, *LPFILTERINFO;
```

And Visual Studio 2019 gives me a warning:

> Warning C26495 Variable '_FILTERINFO::nCustomerID' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).

So, what is the problem here and how would I initialize the variable? As you can see, I don't have a constructor. I don't need them for structures now do I?

*NOTE: Looking into this further, I see my app defines other `struct` that for some reason do not get this same warning. It seems specific to about two or three declarations.*

Comment: You could say `int nCustomerID = 0;` in the `struct` definition, which would be using [default member initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members)

Comment: @CoryKramer: Thanks for responding. But when would that code execute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop the typedef, you are doing C++, so instead write:

```
struct FILTERINFO 
{ 
  int nCustomerID=0; 
  CString sCustomerName; 
};
```

and

```
typedef FILTERINFO* LPFILTERINFO;
```

Normally it is better to not do a typedef of a pointer, use instead  `FILTERINFO*` because sometimes you get unexpected behavior when used with `const`

Comment: Thanks, and I understand your suggested change. The code is very old. But doing this does not appear to remove the warning.

Comment: odd that you still get warning about _FILTERINFO if you removed it.. maybe you have another declaration somewhere else? in another namespace perhaps?

Comment: Clicking on that warning takes me to that line. So I'm not sure how that could be. Also, I noticed I have other `struct`s defined in my app that don't get this warning. Just two or three of them do. Very odd.

Comment: try searching for the struct instead, sometimes intellisense makes no sense :)

Comment: The only references to *FILTERINFO* a solution-wide search finds is in my code. Note that this eliminated the warning on another structure. But not this one. Strange.

Comment: if you are using precompiled headers maybe it would be smart to delete those