# C++ C26495 warning shows up but I don't know how to solve

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

---

```
#pragma once

#include "Card.h"

class Foundation {

    Card* cards[13];
    int current;
    char suit;
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, Foundation& f);
public:

    Foundation(char suit = 'H');
    bool isPlacable(Card* c);
    void put(Card* c);
    bool isFull();
    void clear();
};

/* Warning  C26495  Variable 'Foundation::cards' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6) below. */

Foundation::Foundation(char suit) {

    this->suit = suit;
}
```

---

What is the problem?

Comment: What do you not understand in the warning? The problem is very exactly described,

Comment: [C26495 MEMBER_UNINIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26495?view=msvc-160) and [Warning C26495 on structures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55667784/warning-c26495-on-structures) -- self-expanitory...

Comment: Ok I admit the problem was kinda obvious lol. I didn't read clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the warning because you don't initialize the member in the constructor or use an initializer list.
probably this can fix your warning:

```cpp
class Foundation {

    Card* cards[13] = {};
    int current;
    char suit;
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, Foundation& f);
public:

    Foundation(char suit = 'H');
    bool isPlacable(Card* c);
    void put(Card* c);
    bool isFull();
    void clear();
};
```

Comment: actually this is array default empty initializer  
```c++
int arr[5] = {};    // results in [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```